# UWP: FlipView increases SelectedIndex without user interaction -> OutOfRange -> App Crash

Tags: c#, uwp, selectedindex, flipview

I'm struggling with a kind of a bug I guess.

The App crashes when I keep swiping only with the finger BUT it's not crashing if I use some other method (even for just a single time) to switch to another Item (mouse wheel down, or the arrows which appear after the mouse pointer was moved - even if I tap the arrows with my finger) and continue to swipe with my finger.

---

**What happens while the crash occures?:**

I've observed, that the SelectedIndex (bound Twoway to my VM) of my FlipView starts to increase without any user interaction until the SelectedIndex is higher than my Items count -> OutOfRange -> Crash.

---

**Information about my Machine and project:**

My Solution was originally created under VS2015, my System is Win 10 Pro x64 Build 14393.

I'm using a FlipView with a modified ItemsPanelTemplate:

```
<STackPanel, orientation = horizontal, AreScrollSnapPointsRegular='True'/>
```

My Items for the FlipView are dynamically generated.

My Nuget Packages are:
- CommonServiceLocator (Microsoft) 1.3.0

- MetroLog (Matt Baxter-Reynolds, Oren Novotny) 1.0.1
- Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform (Microsoft) 6.0.2
- Mirosoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed (Microsoft) 2.0.0
- MvvmLight (Laurent Bugnion /GalaSoft) 5.3.0
- Newtonsoft.Json (James Newton-King) 10.0.3
- sqlite-net-pcl (Frank A. Krueger) 1.3.3
- Template10 (Windows Developers) 1.1.12

I know, Windows is not up to date (see my build nr.) but our IT cannot install updates according to compatibility issues with other software we're using.

---

**My thoughts to solve this problem:**

I thought of simulating a [mouse wheel down]-Event but could not find any example or hint how to acheive this in UWP. But I figured out how to simulate a mouse pointer movement, so the arrows appear. But now I don't know how to simulate mouse clicks on one of the arrows, without calculating position and counting pixels.

May be someone of you had a similar problem and could provide some information for me and others with the same issue.

---

**So my questions are:**

- Does anyone know why this behavior occurs?
- Is there a solution for that?

if not:

- How can I simulate a [Mouse Wheel Down]-Event programmatically?
- Is there a way to simulate a Click-Event on one of thoose arrows programmatically?
- Is there another workaround which may help me with my issue?

Any useful information or help are very wellcome.

BTW: At the moment I'm not able to provide example code, but if it's absolutely neccessary, I'll of cause try to reconstruct this behavior in a fresh sln.

Thank you in advance.
Alex

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: All I can say is that I remember having the same error thrown when I bound a Flipview SelectedIndex. I think it had something to do with being -1 when nothing was selected.  I ended up just using SelectedItem for binding.